# Create equal space between anchor points in illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator, creative-cloud, anchor-point

How can I make sure the space between my anchor points are equal? I need the two points to be the same distance from the point in the centre on each side.

[image: guestWho]

Answer (score 5):

you can actually just select the anchor points in question and use the align pallet as long as you don't select ALL of the anchor points. As you select single points, you will see the text in the align pallet change to "align anchor points" instead of "align objects". 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Make sure Smart Guides are enabled, then select those two points with the Direct Selection tool and drag them until centered on the middle anchor.

Adding a guide over the middle anchor sometimes makes it easier.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try :

1. Draw path to divide.
2. Draw a black line to use as a division (a small horizontal line).
3. Copy black line and stroke to other color to contrast with black.
4. Align the two so that two ends meet without changing length. (use
   vertical line as a helper to align)
5. Use these two segments as a pattern brush.
6. Apply pattern to path to divide.
7. Tune with *pattern brush scale* to vary divisions' length and,
   therefore, the number of divisions (This is where the contrasting
   colors of the segments allow you to see the variation of pattern
   scale).
8. Expand appearance.
9. Delete initial path.
10. *Join smooth* resulting segment's overlapping ends to rebuild
     continuous path.

I hope it works.
[image]